# Select the id of an element using jquery

Tags: jquery

Following are the divs i have:

```
<div class="grey-column" id="infoblock1" data-type="datahere"></div>
<div class="green-column" id="infoblock2" data-type="datahere"></div>
<div class="red-column" id="infoblock3" data-type="datahere"></div>
```

I am trying to find out the id of the element which has been clicked, I have this code:

```
$(function(){
    $('.green-column, .red-column, .grey-column').click(function() { 
         id_clicked = this.id; 
         var id_final = '#';
         id_final += id_clicked;
         $("<div>" + $(id_final).attr("data-type") + "</div>").dialog();
    });
});
```

So whenever a user clicks a div, the click function will be fired, and the id of the element clicked is found. But the attr() function doesn't seem to be working here. Please help me out.

Comment: Try this now : http://jsfiddle.net/7gxeY/1/

It's working

Comment: @ NitishT: Your code actually works: http://jsfiddle.net/29HHz/3/  I wouldn't do that (not least because the code falls prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) by not declaring the `id_clicked` variable), but it's functional (unless you're using strict mode). But there's no reason to go indirectly through the `id`; just use `this` itself. You'll want to look at the JavaScript console, etc., to see what *else* is going wrong. It's not really the code you've quoted that's the problem (although I *would* fix it).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks. I will try to see the javascript console and find out the problem. I think the appending of the div to DOM may be the issue, anyways i will find it out. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction!!

Comment: @NitishT: No worries. It seems to work without appending the div to the DOM (which I didn't expect), so...

Comment: My mistake.!! :P I didn't include the proper .js file.! Just included [Google API jQuery CDN](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.22/jquery-ui.min.js) now its working. I feel like an idiot now for asking this.

Comment: @NitishT: We've all done it. :-) And there's a good result, in that you found out you didn't have to deal with the `id`, you could just use `this` directly. Glad that helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `this` is the DOM element clicked, you don't need to go indirectly through the `id` to get at its attributes. Just:

```
$(function(){
    $('.green-column, .red-column, .grey-column').click(function() { 
         $("<div>" + $(this).attr("data-type") + "</div>").dialog();
    });
});
```

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29HHz/2/)

But as your code [*does* work](http://jsfiddle.net/29HHz/3/) provided you're not in strict mode (barring the fact that it falls prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) by not declaring the `id_clicked` variable), you'll want to look at the JavaScript console and such to find out what *else* is going on that's preventing it from working correctly.

Comment: This is confusing me even more. How come this jsfiddle is working but when i put it on the server the dialog fails to popup.

Comment: This might be happening because of other jquery code on your page. It would be conflicting with this.

Comment: @DeadMan: It's inappropriate to spam the question and other people's answers promoting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(function(){
 $('.green-column, .red-column, .grey-column').click(function() { 
     $("<div>" + $(this).data("type") + "</div>").dialog();
 });
});
```

To get the clicked element use `$(this)` and to get `data-type` value use `.data()`

Comment: There's no need to use `data("type")` instead of `attr("data-type")`, in this case they'll do the same thing (since all `data` does is, on the first call to it, read all of the `data-*` attributes into an object with names based on the bit after the `-`, and then return the one you asked for).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(function(){
    $("div").click(function(){
        var div_id = $(this).attr("id");
        $("<div>" + $("#"+div_id).attr("data-type") + "</div>").dialog();
    });
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/7gxeY/1/

Comment: The OP is already using `this.id`. `$(this).attr("id")` is just a really roundabout way to get the same value. This is nothing to do with the actual problem the OP is having.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder , try the demo link now.

Comment: +1 @T.J.Crowder the problem here is that i need to get the dialog() working.

Comment: @DeadMan: A) You don't know who downvoted your answer, and if you assume that the person who commented is also the person who downvoted, you **will** get it wrong quite frequently. Silent downvoting is the norm. B) The answer still doesn't address the OP's issue, and perpetuates the downright bizarre approach of getting the `id` from the element instance and using that to look up...the element instance, which is just completely unnecessary and wasteful.